# Pandas: convert UTC to Local time using timezone, then drop timezone

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have a dataframe with columns:

- **time**: time in UTC format
- **timezone**: the corresponding timezone.

```
                       time             timezone
0  2022-12-28T20:16:31.373Z        Europe/Athens
1  2022-07-28T20:16:31.373Z        Europe/Athens
2  2022-11-01T21:35:35.865Z        Europe/Dublin
3  2022-08-03T19:44:07.611Z  America/Los_Angeles
4  2022-08-02T12:44:44.360Z         Europe/Minsk
```

I want to:

1. Convert UTC time to Local time (using timezone)
2. Remove the Timezone and just keep the datetime

It seems to me that this solution works, but want to make sure that I am not missing something (eg. doesn't deal with dailight saving or something)

```py
import pandas as pd 
 # example dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time' :    ['2022-12-28T20:16:31.373Z', '2022-07-28T20:16:31.373Z', '2022-11-01T21:35:35.865Z', '2022-08-03T19:44:07.611Z', '2022-08-02T12:44:44.360Z'],
    'timezone': ['Europe/Athens', 'Europe/Athens', 'Europe/Dublin', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'Europe/Minsk']

})

 # function 
def get_local_time (timestamp: pd.Timestamp, timezone: str) -> pd.Timestamp: 
    timestamp = pd.to_datetime(timestamp).tz_convert(timezone).replace(tzinfo=None)
    return timestamp

df['local_time'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_local_time(row['time'], row['timezone']), axis = 1).dt.round(freq='S')

print (df)

---
OUT: 
                       time             timezone          local_time
0  2022-12-28T20:16:31.373Z        Europe/Athens 2022-12-28 22:16:31
1  2022-07-28T20:16:31.373Z        Europe/Athens 2022-07-28 23:16:31
2  2022-11-01T21:35:35.865Z        Europe/Dublin 2022-11-01 21:35:36
3  2022-08-03T19:44:07.611Z  America/Los_Angeles 2022-08-03 12:44:08
4  2022-08-02T12:44:44.360Z         Europe/Minsk 2022-08-02 15:44:44
```

Comment: I believe the idiomatic "pandas" way to convert from timezone aware to naive is to `.tz_localize(None)` instead of `.replace(tzinfo=None)` (not entirely certain, both should work). Looks good to me otherwise!

Comment: At the moment, your function signature says it takes a pd.Timestamp, however you feed it a string. So you might move the call to `pd.to_datetime` out of the function, do it before you apply the function. Looks all good to me otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! will apply the changes to the hint then.